# Loop through non-continuous columns

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a worksheet (MWS), with column 1 to 5 having list of names.  I would like if names on column 1 were also found in any of column 2, 3, 4, 5, the name would be put onto column 6.  Here is what I come up with to do the task on column 1.

```
Sub testdup()

Dim MWS As Worksheet, LR As Long, i As Long
Set MWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scope")
For i = 2 To MWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LR = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MWS.Range("F:F"))
If Not MWS.Columns(2).Find(what:=MWS.Cells(i, 1)) Is Nothing Then
MWS.Cells(LR + 1, 6).Value = MWS.Cells(i, 1).Value
End If 
Next i

For i = 2 To MWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LR = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MWS.Range("F:F"))
If Not MWS.Columns(3).Find(what:=MWS.Cells(i, 1)) Is Nothing Then
MWS.Cells(LR + 1, 6).Value = MWS.Cells(i, 1).Value
End If 
Next i

'and repeat the for loop for column 4, 5
```

Now, since I have to do the loop for names on column 2 with column 1, 3, 4, 5 and for names on column 3 with column 1, 2, 4, 5, so on so forth, which involves non-continuous column numbers.  What codes should I add to make MWS.Column(x) variable?  Thank you.

Comment: Why not just check if COUNTIF is >1 for any cells?

Comment: since values within the same column may also recur.  I would like if the values recur in other columns be added.

Comment: You could loop through each column, check countif on the whole range minus countif on that column.

Comment: Using FIND you could construct a range using Union to exclude particular columns.

Comment: @SJR brilliant.  Can you post an answer for my acceptance?  The countif method is good enough already.

Comment: Are the 'names' in columns A:A and B:B unique? Since, you search for names from A:A in all the rest of columns, including the other columns keeping name, should I understand that they are unique per Column (A:A or B:B) but they can be common for that two columns, too? Can such a 'name' occur more then one time per each column to be searched (A:A or B:B)?

Comment: @FaneDuru names can recur within a column, or across other columns.  I would like to list names those recur between columns only.

Comment: So, if a  name which occur in column A:A row 3 also occurs in any other column then A:A must have that name in column 6 (F3). But, if on the same row 3, column B:B it is a different name having multiple occurrences in the other columns except B:B, the name in cell F3, must be replaced by the one found in B:B? And would you like to fill column F:F on each row, even if the values in columns A:A or B:B have multiple occurrences in the other columns?

Comment: @FaneDuru let's say
ColA   ColB   ColC  ColD  ColE
John   Mary   Paul
John   Paul    Joe
Alan   Peter   Jane
John   Alan    Alan
Joe     Irene
          Jack
          Paul

Column F should look like
Alan
Joe
Paul

Comment: @FaneDuru let's say
Col A - John John Alan John Joe
Col B - Mary Paul Peter Alan Irene Jack Paul
Col C - Paul Joe Jane Alan
Col F should look like Alan Joe Paul
Please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Not so easy to understand what you mean, without names separation (by comma, for instance, or being between double quotes). Should I understand that your columns can have different number of records? I mean ColA looks to have 5 names and colB has 7... Should I understand that in column F:F must be only unique names? If yes, column F:F will start be filled from the second row up to the last unique name having more occurrences?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes you are correct.  Columns can have different number of records.  ColA had 5 while ColB had 6.  ColF should have unique names, those were names occurred in more than one column.

Comment: Now it's clear. Since you already accepted an answer, I will prepare another one only for the sake of playing with arrays, slices and arrays sort... No need to remove duplicates. The code does that. And it has to work even if your UsedRange does not start from the first row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method using `COUNTIF`. I haven't tested it so let me know how you get on.

This doesn't check if the value has already been placed in column F. If you wanted this you could do another simple COUNTIF check on column F before adding the value.

```
Sub testdup()

Dim MWS As Worksheet, r As Long, rData As Range, c As Long

Set MWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scope")
Set rData = MWS.Range("A2", MWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 5)

With WorksheetFunction
    For c = 1 To 5
        For r = 1 To rData.Rows.Count
            If .CountIf(rData, rData.Cells(r, c)) - .CountIf(rData.Columns(c), rData.Cells(r, c)) > 0 Then
                MWS.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = rData.Cells(r, c).Value
            End If
        Next r
    Next c
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: cool.  I shall do a remove duplicate on column F afterwards.  Thank you.

Comment: and I added another countif.  not too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Try, please the next code, too. It uses only arrays and working only in memory, it should be fast enough for big range of data.

It loads the intersection of the used range with first five used range columns, in an array (`arrMWS`). Then slices each column of the array, putting each slice in an array of arrays. Iterates between each array row and using `Filter` array (with `True` it returns the number of occurrences) on the specific slice replaces `Count` function to determine occurrences. Checking the condition of more then one `filtered` elements in the slice. The final array is checked (in the same way) if the specific name exists. If not, it is added. I commented each code line, which may be not so clear related to what it does, in a way simple to be understood, I think. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. Only in case you want to understand...

```
Sub testdupArrays()
Dim MWS As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arrMWS As Variant, arrFin As Variant
Dim a As Application, arrCol(1 To 5) As Variant, k As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Set a = Application ' to make code lines shorter
Set MWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scope")
lastRow = MWS.UsedRange.Rows.count + MWS.UsedRange.Row 'last used row in case of different columns number of rows
arrMWS = Intersect(MWS.UsedRange, MWS.Range("A1:E" & lastRow)).value 'load an array from the fifth columns of the used range
 'create an array of arrays, each of them representing a column:
 For i = 1 To 5
    arrCol(i) = a.Transpose(a.Index(arrMWS, 0, i))
 Next

 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrMWS, 1) * 2): k = 1 'redim the array collecting the names which match conditions
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrMWS, 1) 'iterate between the arrMWS rows
    For j = 1 To 2 ' deal with columb A and B
        'if checked value is not empty or it does not already exist in the final array:
        If arrMWS(i, j) <> "" And UBound(Filter(arrFin, arrMWS(i, j), True)) = -1 Then
            'if it exists in the other columns (excluding the analized column using IIf):
            If UBound(Filter(arrCol(1), arrMWS(i, j), True)) > IIf(j = 1, UBound(arrCol(1)), -1) Or _
                    UBound(Filter(arrCol(2), arrMWS(i, j), True)) > IIf(j = 2, UBound(arrCol(2)), -1) Or _
                    UBound(Filter(arrCol(3), arrMWS(i, j), True)) > -1 Or _
                    UBound(Filter(arrCol(4), arrMWS(i, j), True)) > -1 Or _
                    UBound(Filter(arrCol(5), arrMWS(i, j), True)) > -1 Then
                arrFin(k) = arrMWS(i, j):  k = k + 1 'the element is loaded in the final array
            End If
        End If
    Next j
 Next i
  ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To k - 1) 'redim the final array according to the real number of loaded elements
                                    'but preserving the existing elements value
  'clear the F:F column area where the values will be returned:
  MWS.Range("F" & MWS.UsedRange.Row & ":F" & MWS.UsedRange.Rows.count * 2).Clear
  'Drop collected data in column F:F, starting with the first row of your worksheet used range.
  MWS.Range("F" & MWS.UsedRange.Row).Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin)
End Sub
```

Comment: It's always interesting and/or instructive to follow alternative ways. - Personally and for better readibility I'd integrate the long condition check into a function :+)

Comment: @FaneDuru hello.  Sorry for getting back late.  Thank you very much for your code.  I tried it but the line arrMWS = Intersect(MWS.UsedRange, MWS.Range("A1:E" & lastRow)).Value 'load an array from the fifth columns of the used range
gave me an error of "Object variable or With block variable not set"  I think I have no idea why such error arises.

Comment: @John Liu: Did you test the code like it is, or made a (small) adaptation of your needs...?

Comment: @FaneDuru once again thank you for your code.  Your code works perfectly.  I think I forgot to fill the table with names before testing at the very beginning!  Now I re-tested it and I love your code.  Thank you.